# Spring jdbcTemplate throws an SQL syntax error exception when creating a trigger

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Is there a way to handle the "DELIMITER $$" in jdbcTemplate.execute() other than parsing the string to remove the DELIMITER lines?

I have a file containing a trigger declaration that I need to execute both from the mysql command line program:

> mysql -uroot --password=secret mydb < trigger.sql

as well is in a spring java console application:

```
// read the file, get the sql string....
jdbcTemplate.execute(sql);
```

The file contains

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER user_OnInsert BEFORE INSERT ON `user` 
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   SET NEW.serverGlobalSequenceNumber = get_next_value('global');
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Removing the DELIMITER lines allows the file to be executed correctly.